# zend amf can not return big-int of MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-amf

Well here is my query and and it works fine and the field friend_id is of type MySQL big-int

"SELECT friend_id FROM  users_friends uf WHERE uf.user_id=1192134553 limit 2"

and the query returns the required result i.e 
100002407532395 ,
100002307531370

now here is my service zend/amf service

```
public function  GetUserAllFreinds($user_id)
{
    $sql    =    "SELECT friend_id FROM  users_friends uf WHERE uf.user_id=$user_id limit 2";
    $res    =    mysql_query($sql) or die(debug($sql).mysql_error());
    return $res;    
}
```

And the service returns me 2147483647. However when i set friend_id to MySQL varchar, it works. why it does not work for big-int??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the annotations before the service method, as follows:

```
/**
@param int $user_id
@return int
*/
```

Also, your code is returning the result of mysql_query. Shouldn't process the result before returning it?

```
$values = array()
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $values[] = $row['friend_id'];
}
```

and then, returning the $values, setting @return to array instead of int.

Comment: Well, it returns correct result when array is returned but what if i want to return an object rather than array.

Comment: well, not all objects can be returned using AMF. If you want to return database records without processing them into custom objects ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) you should take a look at Zend_Db, which I am pretty sure that you can return the DB records using Zend_AMF.